# bad return type in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

The following code compiles fine in IntelliJ and Eclipse, but the JDK compiler 1.8.0_25 complains. First, the code.

```
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public abstract class MyStream<E> {

  static <T> MyStream<T> create() {
    return null;
  }

  abstract MyStream<E> filter(MyPredicate<? super E> predicate);

  public interface MyPredicate<T> extends Predicate<T> {

    @Override
    boolean test(T t);
  }

  public void demo() {
    MyStream.<Boolean> create().filter(b -> b);
    MyStream.<String> create().filter(s -> s != null);
  }
}
```

The output from javac 1.8.0_25 is:

```
MyStream.java:18: error: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression
    MyStream.<Boolean> create().filter(b -> b);
                                       ^
MyStream.java:18: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    MyStream.<Boolean> create().filter(b -> b);
                                            ^
    ? super Boolean cannot be converted to boolean
MyStream.java:19: error: bad operand types for binary operator '!='
    MyStream.<String> create().filter(s -> s != null);
                                             ^
  first type:  ? super String
  second type: <null>
MyStream.java:19: error: incompatible types: incompatible parameter types in lambda expression
    MyStream.<String> create().filter(s -> s != null);
                                      ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
4 errors
```

When I replace `? super E` with simply `E`, JDK compiles successfully.

When I replace `filter(MyPredicate` with `filter(Predicate`, JDK compiles successfully.

Since it works with JDK 1.8.0_60, I suspect it is a compiler bug.

Any details on what caused this and when it has been fixed?

Comment: yes, I too believe it is a compiler bug. try workaround `filter((Boolean b)->b))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a lambda expression appears in a target type with wildcards (as in most cases)

```
  Consumer<? super Boolean> consumer = b->{...}
```

the question arises - what's the type of the lambda expression; in particular, the type of `b`.

Of course, there could be many choices due to the wildcards; e.g. we could explicitly choose

```
  Consumer<? super Boolean> consumer = (Object b)->{...}
```

However, implicitly, `b` should be inferred as `Boolean`. This makes sense since the consumer should only be fed with `Boolean` anyway.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3

> If T is a wildcard-parameterized functional interface type and the lambda expression is implicitly typed, then the ground target type is the non-wildcard parameterization of T

(This probably assumes that wildcards are use properly variance-wise on the target type; we might find some hilarious examples if the assumption doesn't hold)

Answer (score 1):

`<? super E>` includes `Object`, which isn't a `Boolean`. ie

```
MyPredicate<? super E>
```

Could be a

```
MyPredicate<Object>
```

and you can't return an `Object` as a `boolean`.

Try changing your lambda to:

```
MyStream.<Boolean> create().filter(b -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(b));
```

which will compile and execute without error not matter the type of the stream, but will return `true` for elements that are `true` `Boolean` values.

Comment: no - while the target type is `Predicate<? super Boolean>`, the type of the lambda expression should be `Predicate<Boolean>`. (jls#12.27.3). Therefore `b` has a static type of `Boolean`