# Problems understanding lower bounds when used with lambda and Functional Interface

Tags: java, generics, lambda, java-8, predicate

While studying up on Java8 Streams, I came across the following code snippet:

```
Predicate<? super String> predicate = s -> s.startsWith("g");
```

Since the generic parameter is a lower bound, I figured this would not compile.  The way I see it, if an Object is a supertype to a String, then passing in an Object type should break it, since Object does not have a startsWith() function.  However, I was surprised to see it work without any problems.

Further yet, when I tweaked the predicate to take an upper bound:

```
<? extends String>,
```

it would not compile.

I thought I understood the meaning of upper and lower bounds, but obviously, I am missing something.  Can anyone help explain why the lower bound works with this lambda?

Comment: `extends` compiles too -- `Predicate<? extends String> predicate = s -> s.startsWith("g")` -- though, we cannot feed a `String` to this predicate:) see also my [article](http://bayou.io/draft/Capturing_Wildcards.html) on wildcard

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085151/bad-return-type-in-lambda-expression/33085893#33085893

Comment: `Predicate<? super String>` does *not* imply that you can pass `Object` to it (and trying so will create a compiler error). The signature `Predicate<? super String>` just implies that it *might* be a `Predicate<Object>` which is ok, as that predicate still is able to process `String` inputs. In other words, `Predicate<? super String>` says that this predicate can consume strings, regardless of its actual type, so `Predicate<String>` is a valid implementation of `Predicate<? super String>`.

Comment: My apologies for not giving the complete code.  The actual code that didn't compile was the line **boolean test = anyMatch(predicate);** that came afterwards.  The actual predicate line by itself does compile in both upper and lower bounds syntax.  After thinking about it logically for a while, I understand why the anyMatch would have such a signature.

Answer (score 11):

Lambda argument type is exact, it cannot be `? super` or `? extends`. This is covered by [JLS 15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27). It introduces the *ground target type* concept (which is basically the lambda type). Among other things it's stated that:

> If `T` is a wildcard-parameterized functional interface type and the lambda expression is implicitly typed, then the ground target type is the **non-wildcard parameterization** ([§9.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.9)) of T.

Emphasis mine. So essentially when you write

```
Predicate<? super String> predicate = s -> s.startsWith("g");
```

Your lambda type is `Predicate<String>`. It's the same as:

```
Predicate<? super String> predicate = (Predicate<String>)(s -> s.startsWith("g"));
```

Or even

```
Predicate<String> pred = (Predicate<String>)(s -> s.startsWith("g"));
Predicate<? super String> predicate = pred;
```

Given the fact that lambdas type arguments are concrete, after that normal type conversion rules apply: `Predicate<String>` is a `Predicate<? super String>`, or `Predicate<? extends String>`. So both `Predicate<? super String>` and `Predicate<? extends String>` should compile. And both actually work for me on javac 8u25, 8u45, 8u71 as well as ecj 3.11.1.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Lambda default behavior with bounded parameters was at the heart of my confusion.

Answer (score 10):

I just tested it, the assignment itself compiles. What changes is whether you can actually call `predicate.test()`.

Let's take a step back and use a placeholder `GenericClass<T>` for explanation. For type arguments, `Foo` extends `Bar` and `Bar` extends `Baz`.

Extends:
When you declare a `GenericClass<? extends Bar>`, you are saying "I don't know what its generic type argument actually is, but it's a subclass of `Bar`." The actual instance will always have a non-wildcard type argument, but in this part of the code you don't know what the value of it is. Now consider what that means for method invocations.

You know what you've actually got is either a `GenericClass<Foo>` or a `GenericClass<Bar>`. Consider a method that returns `T`. In the former case, its return type is `Foo`. In the latter, `Bar`. Either way, it's a subtype of `Bar` and is safe to assign to a `Bar` variable.

Consider a method that has a `T` parameter. If it's a `GenericClass<Foo>`, then passing it a `Bar` is an error - `Bar` is not a subtype of `Foo`.

So, with an upper bound you can use generic return values, but not generic method parameters.

Super:
When you declare a `GenericClass<? super Bar>`, you are saying "I don't know what its generic type argument actually is, but it's a superclass of `Bar`." Now consider what that means for method invocations.

You know what you've actually got is either a `GenericClass<Bar>` or a `GenericClass<Baz>`. Consider a method that returns `T`. In the former case, it returns `Bar`. In the latter, `Baz`. If it returns a `Baz`, then assigning that value to a `Bar` variable is an error. You don't know which it is, so you can't safely assume anything here.

Consider a method that has a `T` parameter. If it's a `GenericClass<Bar>`, then passing it a `Bar` is legal. If it's a `GenericClass<Baz>`, then passing it a `Bar` is still legal because `Bar` is a subtype of `Baz`.

So, with a lower bound you can use generic method parameters, but not generic return values.

In summary: `<? extends T>` means you can use generic return values but not parameters. `<? super T>` means you can use generic parameters but not return values. `Predicate.test()` has a generic parameter, so you need `super`.

Another thing to consider: The bounds stated by a wildcard are about the actual type argument of the object. Their consequences on the types that you can *use with* that object are the opposite. An upper bound wildcard (`extends`) is a lower bound on the types of variables you can assign return values to. A lower bound wildcard (`super`) is an upper bound on the types you can pass in as parameters. `predicate.test(new Object())` will not compile because, with a lower bound of `String`, it will only accept subclasses of `String`.

More explanations: [Guidelines for Wildcard Use](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html).

Comment: Thank you for your insight. The return type/parameter summarization makes it much easier to understand their usage.

Comment: There's one thing I cannot understand: "The actual instance will always have a non-wildcard type argument". If we say `GenericClass<? extends Bar> g = GenericClass<>();` then, well, in run time `g` will be subject to type erasure. But in compile time the type is known, so looks like at least a `Bar` may be sent as a parameter.

Comment: Ok, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45610023/3868454) clarifies it really well.