# Why is a cast performed against a lambda input parameter?

Tags: java, generics, lambda

I accept that due to the lower bounded wildcard, this predicate should not accept a superclass of `String` without an explicit cast.[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306595/problems-understanding-lower-bounds-when-used-with-lambda-and-functional-interfa),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623189/java-lower-bound-wildcards)] This question is rather about type safety enforcement in the lambda's parameter list.  Given the second block fails compilation, why is the first allowed to compile without a warning?  It appears that in the first case, despite the lambda's parameter declaration, `CharSequence` is being cast to `String` to satisfy predicate's boundary constraint.

```
    Predicate<? super String> predicate1 = (CharSequence c)
       -> c.toString().length() > 2 ;
    System.out.println(predicate1.test("foo"));                 // compiles
```

```
    Predicate<? super String> predicate2 = (CharSequence c)
       -> c.toString().length() > 2 ;
    System.out.println(predicate2.test((CharSequence)"foo"));  // capture error
```

```
error: method test in interface Predicate<T> cannot be applied to given types;
    out.println(predicate2.test((CharSequence)"foo")); 
                          ^
  required: CAP#1
  found: CharSequence
  reason: argument mismatch; CharSequence cannot be converted to CAP#1
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in interface Predicate
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object super: String from capture of ? super String
```

Thanks for the work on this. The issue appears to be an assumption that the lambda and the generic process would forced to consume a `CharSequence`.  However, it's now clear that `String` can be submitted to the lambda without a compiler error, so what's happening in the first case and a `String` is being submitted to both processes.  It's no surprise that the generics process is ignoring the content of the lambda.

Answer (score 4):

```
Predicate<? super String> predicate2 = (CharSequence c)
   -> c.toString().length() > 2 ;
System.out.println(predicate2.test((CharSequence)"foo"));  // capture error
```

The issue is that `predicate2` says it is something which will accept a `String`; you're trying to pass it a `CharSequence`.

If you change the declaration of the variable to

```
Predicate<? super CharSequence> predicate2
```

then it works.

The reason this doesn't work is that you might be passing a `MyCharSequence implements CharSequence` to the predicate:

```
System.out.println(predicate2.test((CharSequence)new MyCharSequence()));
```

This shouldn't be accepted, because the type of the `predicate2` variable says it should only expect to be given an instance of `String`. The compiler only sees the type of the actual parameter as `CharSequence`, so it can't distinguish between "this is a `String`" (would be OK) and "this is a `MyCharSequence`" (wouldn't be OK).

Comment: @user why wouldn't it compile? You've got a `Predicate` whose type says "I want to be able to pass a `String` to this", and you're passing a `String` to it.

Comment: @user you don't know what the type is, but you know that it's some supertype of `String` (or `String` itself), so you can pass a `String` to it safely.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it.  String is-a CharSequence.  A String can be submitted as a CharSequence without a cast.  Unless anyone disagrees I'll withdraw this.

Comment: I'll leave it up and take it down if it gets downvotes.  Thanks for a lot of good work on this.

Answer (score 1):

*It appears that in the first case, despite the lambda's parameter declaration, String is being cast to CharSequence to satisfy predicate's boundary constraint*. You said this referring to the 1st case, but there is nothing being cast to `CharSequence` here.

If you break your 1st case code like this,

```
    final Predicate<CharSequence> charSequencePredicate = (CharSequence c) -> c.toString().length() > 2;
    Predicate<? super String> predicate1 = charSequencePredicate;
    System.out.println(predicate1.test("foo"));
```

You will see that when the `predicate1.test("foo")` is called, "foo" is passed as a `String`, and when this `String` is passed to the `Predicate` as it's argument, the assignment to parameter `c` is done without any casting as `String` implements `Charsequence`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Even though the predicate is expecting a String, there is no reason it can't use a lambda that accepts a CharSequence.